# Play video file in Smart Watch and Android Wear

Tags: android

I like to play my video file in Android Wear, but I came to know that `videoview` is not supported in Android Wear.

Is there an alternative?

```
InputStream ins = MainActivityBackup.this.getResources().openRawResource (R.raw.hyperlapse2);
File tmpFile = null;
OutputStream output;

try {

    tmpFile = File.createTempFile("video","mov");
    output = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

    final byte[] buffer = new byte[102400];
    int read;

    while ((read = ins.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        output.write(buffer, 0, read);
    }
    output.flush();
    output.close();
    ins.close();
} 

catch (IOException e) 
{

e.printStackTrace();

}
```